# How to replace many special characters with "something plus special characters" in R

Tags: regex, r, string, replace

I have this sentence that contains "& / ?".

```
c = "Do Sam&Lilly like yes/no questions?"
```

I want to add a whitespace before and after each of the special characters to get

```
"Do Sam & Lilly like yes / no questions ? "
```

I can only get this by the hard way:

```
c = gsub("[&]", " & ", c)
c = gsub("[/]", " / ", c)
c = gsub("[?]", " ? ", c)
```

But imagine that I have many of these special character, which warrants using [:alnum:]. So I am really looking for a solution that looks like this:

```
gsub("[[:alnum:]]", " [[:alnum:]] ", c)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use [:alnum:] as the second argument this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a capture group reference:

```
gsub("([&/])", " \\1 ", c)
```

Here we replace `"&"` or `"/"` with themselves (`"\\1"`) padded with spaces.  The `"\\1"` means "use the first matched group from the pattern.  A matched group is a portion of a regular expression in parentheses.  In our case, the `"([&/])"`.

You can expand this to cover more symbols / special characters by adding them to the character set, or by putting in an appropriate regex special character.

note: you probably shouldn't use `c` as a variable name since it is also the name of a very commonly used function.

Comment: Is there a way to generalise this if the special characters are not known before hand (say with punct)

Comment: ah `gsub("([[:punct:]])", " \\1 ", x)` ... although this would mess up with full stops etc

Comment: @user20650 absolutely, just use the desired regex set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I didn't know the "\\1" trick.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you mean this,

```
> c <- "Do Sam&Lilly like yes/no questions?"
> gsub("([^[:alnum:][:blank:]])", " \\1 ", c)
[1] "Do Sam & Lilly like yes / no questions ? "
```

`[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]` negated POSIX character class which matches any character but not of an alphanumeric or horizontal space character. BY putting the pattern inside a capturing group, it would capture all the special characters. Replacing the matched special chars with `space`+`\\1` (*refers the characters which are present inside the first group*) + `space` will give you the desired output.  You could use `[:space:]` instead of `[:blank:]` also.

Comment: Both are great answers. I am marking BrodieG's as "the" correct answer simply because he explained in more details. Thank you both!

Comment: @wen instead of adding each single character into the list, why don't have a simple regex which matches all the special chars?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your regex patterns outside of `gsub` and then pass them in. I see the BrodieG refreed to the pattern enclosed in  `"(...)"`as a "capture group". The material inside square-brackets, `"[...]"` are called "character classes" in the R-help page for `?regex`. The "\1" is a "back-reference" and since the regex-help page seems to be silent on the matter of what to call strings enclosed in parentheses, I've probably just been pushed a bit further along in my understanding of regex terminology. :

```
your_chars <- c("!@#$%^&*", "()_+", "?/")
patt <- paste0( "([", paste0(your_chars,collapse=""), "])", collapse="")
gsub(patt, " \\1 ", ct)
#[1] "Do Sam & Lilly like yes / no questions ? "
```

You would need to use `gsub` rather than `sub` if you want to replace more than one instance ins a character value.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your meaning. Will clarify in the body.