# gsub only part of pattern

Tags: r, string, gsub

I want to use gsub to correct some names that are in my data. I want names such as "R. J." and "A. J." to have no space between the letters.

For example:

```
x <- "A. J. Burnett"
```

I want to use gsub to match the pattern of his first name, and then remove the space:

```
gsub("[A-Z]\\.\\s[A-Z]\\.", "[A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\\.", x)
```

But I get:

```
[1] "[A-Z].[A-Z]. Burnett"
```

Obviously, instead of the [A-Z]'s I want the actual letters in the original name. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463495/how-to-replace-many-special-characters-with-something-plus-special-characters

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use capture groups by enclosing patterns in `(...)`, and refer to the captured patterns with `\\1`, `\\2`, and so on. In this example:

```
x <- "A. J. Burnett"
gsub("([A-Z])\\.\\s([A-Z])\\.", "\\1.\\2.", x)
[1] "A.J. Burnett"
```

Also note that in the replacement you don't need to escape the `.` characters, as they don't have a special meaning there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a look-ahead (`(?=\\w\\.)`) and a look-behind (`(?<=\\b\\w\\.)`) to target such spaces and replace them with "".

```
x <- c("A. J. Burnett", "Dr. R. J. Regex")
gsub("(?<=\\b\\w\\.) (?=\\w\\.)", "", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A.J. Burnett"   "Dr. R.J. Regex"
```

The look-ahead matches a word character (`\\w`) followed by a period (`\\.`), and the look-behind matches a word-boundary (`\\b`) followed by a word character and a period.